# Laravel Debugbar with laravel api routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a Laravel API.

The front end application is completely separate from Laravel.

All Laravel routes are located in **routes/api.php**

Is there any way to make the Laravel Debugbar work in this case?

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**barryvdh/laravel-debugbar** needs to be installed on your Laravel project (actually all debuggers need to be present within the project to audit every request) and get its files served to the frontend to work (edit repsonses with `Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php`).

I won't say that it is impossible to get its insights on a separate front, who knows if you are ready to fork the project and communicate with the debug bar APIs.

For a simpler alternatives you can use:

1. **laravel/telescope** [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/telescope) [repo](https://github.com/laravel/telescope)
2. **Clockwork** browser extension [website](https://underground.works/clockwork/) [repo](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork)
3. **spatie/laravel-ray**(paid) [website](https://myray.app/) [docs](https://spatie.be/docs/ray/v1/introduction)

Comment: It is also possible to use this one
https://github.com/adobrovolsky97/illuminar

Answer (score 2):

"You can view the history of the Debugbar with the browse button (third from the right). If you have non-api page for the same app, you can open the API requests. You can filter by url/ip etc."

- *Barryvdh (author of laravel-debugbar)*

*[Source Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-do-i-use-debugbar-on-an-api-server-with-no-views)*